# Automate filtering of Excel sheet based on criteria in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this is a common question, but I'm a bit new to the world of Excel-VBA and I've been having trouble finding a way of doing exactly what I need.

I have a fairly large sheet and need to be able to delete rows based on criteria in two columns.

Below is some very basic data to explain what I need to do...

**Col A**

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Apple
4. Apple
5. Orange
6. Grape

**Col B**

1. Blue
2. Red
3. Green
4. 
5. Yellow
6. Black

I need to remove any rows where there is a duplicate value in Col A and a blank value beside it in Col B. So, in the example data above I want to delete Row 4 as that has a duplicate value (Apple) in Col A and a blank value in Col B.

Obviously in the example I could easily delete that row manually. But the actual sheet contains 10,000s of rows and the data in column A will be URLs rather than nice simple fruits!

I've had a look at using filtering, but can't work out a good (quick) method of achieving the result I need. So I'm thinking it will have to be Excel VBA but I'm more than happy to be proved wrong. If VBA is the way to go, does anyone have a routine I could use/adapt? I've found a few that will delete duplicates and a few that will delete blanks. But I'm really struggling to combine them so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mrig & J.B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub DeleteBlankDuplicate()
    Dim current As String
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        current = ActiveCell.Address
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
            If ((ActiveSheet.Range(current).Value = ActiveCell.Value) And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "") Then
                ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            End If
        Loop
        ActiveSheet.Range(current).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

You have not mentioned whether you also want to delete rows where both `Column A` and `Column B` have same values. So if you want to **delete rows with duplicate values in Column A and Column B or Column B is Blank** then replace the `IF` condition in the code above to the following:

```
If ((ActiveSheet.Range(current).Value = ActiveCell.Value) And (ActiveSheet.Range(current).Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "") Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code for the example you have given in OP. You can edit the code as per your requirement. Please take backup of your original file before trying this as it deletes the rows.

```
 Sub RemoveData()
    Dim LastRow, Filtred_Rows_Count As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A1:B" & LastRow)
    Range("A1:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True

    For Each c In Range([J2], Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
            With Rng
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=c.Value
                Filtred_Rows_Count = Intersect(Columns(1), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
                If Filtred_Rows_Count > 2 Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Next
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```